# JPA join queries with where from each

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with JPA join. As database query something like this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM votingstats
INNER JOIN enginename ON enginename.id = votingstats.engine_name_id
WHERE engine_name LIKE 'zz'
  AND type_of_game_used_by_that_engine LIKE 'yy'
  AND vote_pack_name = 'xx'
```

However in Java JPA, I have a problem cause working query looks like this and it works fine:

```
 CriteriaQuery<VotingStats> criteria= 
 criteriaBuilder.createQuery(VotingStats.class);
    Root<VotingStats> currentElo = criteria.from(VotingStats.class);
    Join<VotingStats, EngineName> join = currentElo.join("engineNameId");
    CriteriaQuery<VotingStats> eloJoinQuery = criteria
            .where(
                criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                join.get("engineName"), engineName),
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                join.get("typeOfGameUsedByThatEngine"), typeOfGame.getTypeOfGame())
                )
            );
```

However after adding `votePackName`, it breaks when I try to refer to the `VotingStats` entity:

```
  CriteriaQuery<VotingStats> criteria= 
  criteriaBuilder.createQuery(VotingStats.class);
    Root<VotingStats> currentElo = criteria.from(VotingStats.class);
    Join<VotingStats, EngineName> join = currentElo.join("engineNameId");
    CriteriaQuery<VotingStats> eloJoinQuery = criteria
            .where(
                criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                join.get("engineName"), engineName),
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                join.get("typeOfGameUsedByThatEngine"), typeOfGame.getTypeOfGame()),
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                join.get("votePackName"), votePackName)
                )
            );
```

Entities looks like this (but they works fine if it is normal join):

```
@Entity
@Data
public class VotingStats {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="votingstats_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="votingstats_seq", sequenceName="votingStats_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Integer id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "vote_pack_name")
private String votePackName;

@Basic
@Column(name = "vote_amount")
private Integer voteAmount;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "engine_name_id")
private EngineName engineNameId;
}
```

and second entity is:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class EngineName {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="engineName_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="engineName_seq", sequenceName="enginename_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Integer id;


@Basic
@Column(name = "engine_name")
private String engineName;


@Basic
@Column(name = "type_of_game_used_by_that_engine")
private String typeOfGameUsedByThatEngine;

}
```

This is the error I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [votePackName] on this ManagedType [chess.database.entities.EngineName]
>
> at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128)
> at  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:116)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
> at chess.database.dao.VotingStatsDAO.findByEngineName(VotingStatsDAO.java:32)

Comment: `join` represents the class `EngineName`. There is no such property (`votePackName`) on that class (`join.get("votePackName")`). The message tells you this. Property `votePackName` would exist on `currentElo`, since that represents class `VotingStats`. aka user error

Comment: Thanks,  after your comment i add 


  _Root<VotingStats> fromVotingStats = criteria.from(VotingStats.class);_

and 

       _criteriaBuilder.equal(
   fromVotingStats.get("votePackName"), votePackName)_

and it works fine now :)